# how to store a Json object using spark java framework

Tags: java, mongodb, class, model, spark-streaming

I want to create a model whose structure is as shown below

```
"SettingsConfiguration":{
   loadingOccupancy:[
      {
         berthId:Number,
         laneId:Number,
         berthCapacity:Number,
         routeNo:String,
         speciallyChallengedCapacity:Number
      }
   ],
   smsNotification:{
      phoneNo:Number,
      smsSendingStatus:Boolean
   }
}
```

using spark java ,I am able to do for the simple structure as shown below

```
package com.models;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

public class Map {

    private String id;
    private String title;


    public Map(BasicDBObject dbObject) {
        this.id = ((ObjectId) dbObject.get("_id")).toString();
        this.title = dbObject.getString("title");


    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

But not sure how to construct the class for the above data structure
please help how to construct the class i.e, how to parse and store the above JSON format which is coming from the request body

Answer (score 0):

Steps which you could try > 
1.Method to read the request using the paramater of the method HttpServletRequest request eg : protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request).
2. And try to write a method like this :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request){
String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
try {

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            JSONArray entryArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.get("SettingsConfiguration")
                    .toString());
            JSONObject entryObj = entryArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray loadingOccupancyArray = new JSONArray(entryObj.get("loadingOccupancy")
                    .toString());
            JSONObject loadingOccupancyObject = loadingOccupancyArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject sender = (JSONObject) loadingOccupancyObject.get("berthId");
            JSONObject recipient = (JSONObject) loadingOccupancyObject.get("laneId");
            JSONObject message = (JSONObject) loadingOccupancyObject.get("laneId");
            System.out.println("message = " + message.get("text"));
            System.out.println("sender = " + sender.get("id"));
            System.out.println("recipient = " + recipient.get("id"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Use Jackson [Java JSON parser (http://jackson.codehaus.org)] library. Please refer [Parsing JSON File Java](http://api.ning.com/files/PELnmu%2ANVi7sYK6AgRk1ulZ8xy8S2GxfrFBx7sENdXaUha1%2A7mzQ5rbUNdXa5X%2A5P%2A2jIE%2A83NPAyaHmtNq8Osjece5RtO5C/jsonparsingwithjackson.pdf) for more information